# Toyota 2010 FJ - Oil Sludge Issue - Worth Flushing?

Tags: sludge

Engine started to blow smoke and engine light game on. Checked oil had sludge on dip stick. I have been going 8000 miles between changes. Has 94000 miles. Took in and they said new engine or they can try to flush sludge. 50-50 chance it will work. Is it worth spending 600 flushing engine? They said that scoping cylinders they look fine. They said compression is ok. Any help would be great!

Comment: What currency? 600 USD, Euros, or GBP to do an oil flush is ridiculous.

Comment: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/38032/when-is-an-engine-flush-a-good-idea  Have your changed the oil since you discovered the sludge?

Comment: entertaining and informative ( did i say entertaining ). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Thszl7visBU Pay attention to the advice at minute 5:56 in the video.